# Href how to pass dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

[![enter image description here][1]][1]In href how to pass path with dynamic data, below I'm giving my code:

```
var abc = response[i].DocumentName;
var photoName = "<a href='@Url.Content("~/UploadImage/")" + abc +'" target="_blank" >'+response[i].DocumentName+'</a>';
```

> in debugger mode i am getting like this:-

```
photoName = "<a href='/UploadImage/jpeg2_10514.jpg target="_blank" id="servicedocu">jpeg2_10514.jpg</a>"
```

which is not working for me

Comment: You can do like this, `"<a href='../UploadImage/" + abc +'" target="_blank" >'+response[i].DocumentName+'</a>"`

Comment: var photoName = "<a href='@Url.Content(\"~/UploadImage/\")" + abc + "' target='_blank' >"+response[i].DocumentName+"</a>";

Comment: var photoName = "<a href='@Url.Content("~/UploadImage/")' + abc +' target="_blank" >'+response[i].DocumentName+'</a>';

Comment: @karan did you solve the problem?

Comment: yes @hsnbl , but i used some other trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var photoName = "<a href=\"@Url.Content('~/UploadImage/')" + abc + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + response[i].DocumentName + "</a>";
```

In Javascript you have to escape doublequotes `"` with a backslash `\` if you want them to appear in the string.

The backslash in `+ abc + "\"` is there to escape the second `"` to enclose the href in doublequotes.

**EDIT**

I added the missing doublequote befor the anchor tag according to the tip of karan.

Comment: before starting of anchor tag there should be single or double quotes,,,,,i think u missed it .. ma kobi

Comment: after used your code i am getting error that **CS1012: Too many characters in character literal**